# Unable to join windows server 2012 r2 domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-domain

Hi I'm using two virtual box machines one machine is win7 and other win server 2012 r2. When I try to join the domain it get the following message An Active directory Domain Controller (AD DC) could not be contacted.
I have done ipconfig/all if it helps 
I did nslookup found the DNS request time out. So where to from here? How do I fix this issue?

P.S I'm new at this!

---

Vbox network settings Internal cable is connected.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ipconfig/all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : SERVER2012VM_SH
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : nwk305sh.local
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : nwk305sh.local

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-50-1C-3F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.10.2(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.0.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.10.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.10.2
                                       10.1.10.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Win7 `ipconfig`

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : NWK305sh.local
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.10.100
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.0.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.10.1

Tunnel adapter isatap.NWK305sh.local:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : NWK305sh.local

C:\Users\Win7-SH>
```

Comment: run `ipconfig` on both, -windows 7 and w2k12 and add result  to your question. Also add information how interfaces set in Vbox (NATed or bridged)

Comment: Vbox internal network

Comment: In VBox in adapter setting click on "Advanced" to expand property and in tick checkbox -"Cable Connected" in both VMs, P.S. Please edit your original question with extra details instead of posting an answer. To make your post readable - check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) page how you can format your post

Comment: Done that and the cable is connected.

Comment: Can you ping each other machines? Check this [link](http://www.brianlinkletter.com/how-to-use-virtualbox-to-emulate-a-network/) how to setup closed internal network

Comment: All good with ping test.

Comment: If you setup correctly DNS server on w2k12 then try to join domain then

Comment: The DNS not setup right. Not sure where I've gone wrong do know  any how to guides on setting up DNS.

Comment: Please post an `ipconfig /all` from your Win7 client.  Also, is your server configured to be a DNS server?

Answer (score 0):

The windows server 2012 r2 should have a dns role and it should have its own DNS ( 127.0.0.1) or his IP address and on the windows 7 you should configure your DNS manually as the same ip that windows server 2012 r2 is assigned to. You should be able to ping the DNS aka the IP of the windows server so you would be able to join the domain .